# How to test module in a module with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this set up

```
module A do
  module B do
     def foo
  end
end
```

Inside rspec I'm trying to test foo.

My rspec file is like this

```
describe A::B do
  describe "#foo" do
    A::B.foo ...
  end 

end
```

I get the error NoMethodError: undefined method foo for A::B:Module

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `require` the file that contains the module you want to test in your spec file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `module A do` syntax seems to be wrong - there shouldn't be a `do` word. The second thing is that you tries to call foo method on a module `A::B` (there is no class method defined on `A::B` - foo is an instance method). Your code should looks like:

```
module A
  module B
    def self.foo
    end
  end
end
```

*(In this case, you can call `A::B.foo`)

OR if you want to have foo as an instance method:

```
module A
  module B
    def foo
    end
  end
end
```

In this case you cannot call `A::B.foo`, but you can create a class, which can include `A::B` module:

```
class Test
  include A::B
end
```

Now you can call Test.new.foo

Regarding rspec testing:

- class method: as you described
- instance method:

  - define Test class in your spec and then test this class
  - include this module to your rspec context (ugly way)

Answer (score 1):

`::A::B#foo` is not a method on the module object itself. It is a method the module makes available via the Ruby lookup hierarchy to objects which inherit it. Inheritance in this case could be extending or including the module.

```
class Fooish
  include A::B
end

a_foo = Fooish.new
a_foo.foo

an_object = Object.new
an_object.extend(A::B)
an_object.foo
```

People are different in their approaches. If I had an object that already included `A::B` in my code base I may use that for my tests. If I was writing a library which made `A::B` available for use, then I would probably test that when my module is included/extended it does what I expect.

An example of the latter, which is also a more isolated type of unit test, using RSpec may look something like the following:

```
RSpec.describe A::B do
  it "makes #foo available" do
    an_object = Object.new
    expect(an_object).not_to respond_to(:foo)
    an_object.extend(A::B)
    expect(an_object).to respond_to(:foo)
  end

  it "does whatever foo does" do
    an_object = Object.new
    an_object.extend(A::B)
    expect(an_object.foo).to eq "something"
  end
end
```

Note that the 2nd test will implicitly test the behavior of the first test. It is up to you if you wish to include both or not.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly tidy way of setting this up would be:

```rb
RSpec.describe A::B do                                
  subject(:object) { Object.new.extend(described_class) }

  describe '#foo' do
    expect(object.foo).to eq('whatever')
  end
end
```